# Wordpress Settings API update_option for select option with text area

Tags: wordpress

How can i create different option and update them with update_option?

For each option there should be a text area witch should be updated

```
<select>
  <option value="option-one"></option>
     <textarea>option-one</textarea>
  <option value="option-two"></option>
     <textarea>option-two</textarea>
  <option value="option-three"></option>
     <textarea>option-three</textarea>
</select>
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Check this one http://wpsettingsapi.jeroensormani.com/

Comment: Thanks, but i need for each select option an text area, can i do that with this generator ?